# How to fix hiding for the first three turns when replaying a game of Tic Tac Toe in C++?

Tags: c++

I am creating a game of Tic Tac Toe in C using a console based interface. Two players go against each other by choosing a number from 1-9 to place their pieces on the board. I have this strange issue that when the game is completed (Such as if one player wins the game or the game ends in a draw). The user(s) is offer a prompt to play again.

If the player types in "Y" to play again, the board is cleared and then is shown up again. However for the first three turns, when the player types a number to choose a position on the board, the console will give out an "error" saying "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed", however on the fourth turn, the game carries on as normal with all the pieces the players previously selected during this round is now displayed on the board with no "errors" printed to the user. Is there anyway to fix this strange glitch? Sorry if I worded this poorly. Thank you.

```
//Libaries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;
//Indentifers
void gamescreen(); //Used to display the board
char gamecondition(); //This is indentifer is used to check the game is won lost/draw
void playerturn();
void playernames();
int resultsscreen();
int turn;
int playerinput(int playerchoice);
int Player1Score, Player2Score;

//Variables
//int menuchoice; //Not Neeeded for now
char PlayerPiece = 'X';
char GameWinner; //Declare for game winner
char board[3][3] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' }; //Creates a 3 by 3 matrix, which is basically the board.
int playerchoice; //Reason why playerchoice is a int rather than a char is because
string Player1Name, Player2Name, Player;
char finalchoice;

void playernames()
{
    cout << "Player 1 please enter your name" << endl; //Asks for the first username
    cin >> Player1Name; // Gets the first user name
    cout << "Player 2 please enter your name" << endl; //Asks for the second username
    cin >> Player2Name; // Gets the second user name
    cout << "Player 1 Name is: " << Player1Name << " " << "and Player 2 name is: " << Player2Name << endl; //Displays Usernames
}

void gamescreen() //Displays the board on the screen to the players
{
    system("cls"); //CLears the screen again, to make the game clean and tidy
    cout << "SCOREBOARD: " << Player1Name << ": " << Player1Score << " " << Player2Name << ": " << Player2Score << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    cout << board[0][0] << " | " << board[0][1] << " | " << board[0][2] << endl;
    cout << board[1][0] << " | " << board[1][1] << " | " << board[1][2] << endl;
    cout << board[2][0] << " | " << board[2][1] << " | " << board[2][2] << endl;
}

void playercheck()
{
    if (PlayerPiece == 'X')
    {
        cout << "It is " << Player1Name << " Turn, please put select a piece on the board" << endl;
    }
    if (PlayerPiece == 'O')
    {
        cout << "It is " << Player2Name << " Turn, please put select a piece on the board" << endl;
    }
    cin >> playerchoice;
    playerinput(playerchoice);
}

int playerinput(int playerchoice)
{
    if (playerchoice > 9 || playerchoice < 1 || cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Please enter a number from 1-9!" << endl;
        playercheck();
    }
    else
    {
        if (playerchoice == 1) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[0][0] == '1') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[0][0] = PlayerPiece; //If the condition is true, then it replaces that board space with the player piece
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 2) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[0][1] == '2') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[0][1] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 3) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[0][2] == '3') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[0][2] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 4) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[1][0] == '4') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[1][0] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 5) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[1][1] == '5') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[1][1] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 6) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[1][2] == '6') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[1][2] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 7) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[2][0] == '7') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[2][0] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 8) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[2][1] == '8') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[2][1] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 9) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[2][2] == '9') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[2][2] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter in a valid number!" << endl;
            playercheck();
            //Fail safe just in case the first one failed somehow.
        }
    }
    //The if statements about choices, etc. Checking if this space has not been picked yet

    //NEED TO CHANGE ALL OF THE NUMBERS
    return 1;
}

void playerturn()
{
    if (PlayerPiece == 'X')
        PlayerPiece = 'O';
    else
        PlayerPiece = 'X';
}

char gamecondition() //This is used to check the win conidtion aka who won or if not how does this game draw?
{
    //Checks for the first player
    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[0][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X'; //Basically this checks if the there is three in a row in the board, if show it returns the value X, which will be shown in the main. (Basically if GameWinner == X, cout << "Player1 wins!" << endl;
    if (board[1][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[2][0] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][0] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][1] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[2][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X'; //Returns X to the gamecondition()

                    //Checks for the second player
    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O'; //Basically this checks if the there is three in a row in the board, if show it returns the value X, which will be shown in the main. (Basically if gameconidition == X, cout << "Player1 wins!" << endl;
    if (board[1][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[2][0] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][0] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][1] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[2][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    else
        return '/'; //If it isn't either O or X then returns '/' which shows it's a draw
}

int main()
{
    playernames();
    turn = 0; //This is a turn counter, this will be used to determine the draw (Without it the game will keep on going)
    gamescreen(); //Displays the game screen again
    while (1)
    {
        turn++; //If the game hasn't been completed yet then adds 1 to the number counter
        playercheck();
        gamescreen();
        if (gamecondition() == 'X')
        {
            cout << Player1Name << " wins!" << endl;
            Player1Score++;
            resultsscreen();
        }
        else if (gamecondition() == 'O')
        {
            cout << Player2Name << " wins!" << endl;
            Player2Score++;
            resultsscreen();
        }
        else if (gamecondition() == '/' && turn == 9)
        {
            cout << "It's a draw!" << endl;
            resultsscreen();
        }
        playerturn();
    }
}

int resultsscreen()
{
    cout << "The current score is:" << endl;
    cout << Player1Name << ":" << Player1Score << endl;
    cout << Player2Name << ":" << Player2Score << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to play again, Y/N?" << endl;

    cin >> finalchoice;

    if (finalchoice == 'Y' || finalchoice == 'y')
    {
        turn = 0;
        board[0][0] = '1', board[0][1] = '2', board[0][2] = '3';
        board[1][0] = '4', board[1][1] = '5', board[1][2] = '6';
        board[2][0] = '7', board[2][1] = '8', board[2][2] = '9';
        system("cls");
        gamescreen();
        playercheck();
        playerturn();
        playerinput(playerchoice);
    }
    if (finalchoice == 'N' || finalchoice == 'n')
    {
        if (Player1Score > Player2Score)
        {
            cout << Player1Name << " wins!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
        if (Player1Score < Player2Score)
        {
            cout << Player2Name << " wins!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (Player1Score == Player2Score)
        {
            cout << "It's a draw!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is. It is called "debugging". Using a debugger is one of a good way of debugging. Another way is to print information to check.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Why are you calling `gamescreen()`, `playercheck()`, etc. in `resultscreen()` when you already call all of those things in the main loop?

Comment: This is some seriously ugly code. Functions should perform a well defined task, and then return. They should not be used as a goto. Why are you trying to avoid loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling

```
playerinput();
playercheck();
gamescreen();
```

Functions from

```
resultsscreen();
```

which is unnecessary and causing your problem. Remove these function from `resultsscreen()` as they will be called again in you main function loop if the user choose to continue the game(and hence the reason it shows the slot is already taken).